# ASP.NET Core - are files put in the Shared folder under Pages (where the Razor pages reside) publicly accessible?

Tags: api, asp.net, confidentiality, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Are files put into the Pages/Shared folder public to the whole WWW if the website is hosted publicly? I am asking since I want to implement a partial view load thru a controller and want to know whether it's secure.

I am using ASP.NET Core version 6 if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, no. Those are files used to render pages on server side. If you will not modify the configuration of where from static files are hosted or the IIS setup (open directory browser feature) you should be secure.

Comment: Does this apply to the default settings of Azure Web Apps too?

Comment: As far as I know ASP.NET Core apps behave the same on Azure Web Apps and on premise.

Comment: I mean the IIS settings on the Azure Web App

Comment: Yes. It is the same on IIS Azure Web Apps.